# I want to know a banner animation like keyboard typing visualization

Tags: jquery, animation

http://www.sbnetworkbd.com/home.html please see this website. I want to know about that welcome animation like keyboard typing effect . I want to know how they did it?

Comment: but what have you tried?

Comment: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at this amazing jQuery plugin : http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/**

Simple integration and full control of speed and effects.

> Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wdxurdsf/

**Required Assets : `jQuery` and `typed.js`**

Comment: Brother may i get your skype/ gmail / facebook ID  I need your help

Comment: ameenulla0007 at g /\/\ail dot com, you can find me with the same ID. Thanks.